# Density argument for subspaces of vector valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider $\Omega \times (0,T) = Q$, and the spaces

- $A=W_2^{1,1}(Q) = \{ u \in L^2(Q): \nabla u, u_t \in L^2(Q) \text{ and } \int_0^T ||u_t||_{L^2(\Omega)}^2+||u||_{H^1(\Omega)}^2 <\infty\}$
- $B = W(0,T)=\{u \in L^2(0,T; H^1(\Omega)): u_t \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega)^*) \text{ and} \int_0^T ||u_t||_{H^1(\Omega)^*}^2+||u||_{H^1(\Omega)}^2 <\infty\}$

It is known that $A$ is dense in $B$. Can we say the same for $A_2 = A\cap \{u(T)=0\}$ and $B_2 = B\cap \{u(T)=0\}$?

Clearly, $A_2$ is not dense in $A$, nor $B_2$ is dense in $B$. Maybe we can recover this property as follows. Let $b\in b_2$ and find $a_n \rightarrow b$ in $B$. Pick a mollifier $\phi^n$ which is $1$ in $[0,T-2/n]$ and $0$ in $[T-1/n, T]$. The idea would be to have $a_n\phi^n$ converge to $b$, but as far as I understand, this would require $||\phi^n_t||_{L^2(0,T)}$ to go to zero, which I don't see happening.

Is the statement true? Can it be proven along the lines of what I was doing, or do you have another way? Thanks.

Comment: I thinks the statement is true and might be proven following your idea. For convergence, you need $(1-\phi^n)a_n  \to0$ (not $\phi^n\to0$). Maybe dominated convergence works?

Comment: @daw this is a good idea: the $L^1$ time derivative of the sequence of mollifiers can be asked to be uniformly bounded, and it converges a.e. to $1$ (or $0$, as you mentioned) and this would show the claim. Would you agree?

Comment: Seems it is not so easy: I do not see how to obtain strong convergence in the time derivative.

Comment: @daw You're right, it doesn't work so easily.